# What does running node with a module name do?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js so I'm pretty sure that I am doing something wrong however I would like to understand what is going on.

I tried to run this:

```
$ node tslint
$
```

Which output nothing. It didn't fail either.

Checking the help:

```
$ node --help
Usage: node [options] [ -e script | script.js | - ] [arguments]
       node inspect script.js [arguments]
```

I suspect that I should have passed in the path to the js file instead.

```
$ node node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint
No files specified. Use --project to lint a project folder.
```

Sure enough that printed an error since I didn't pass a file name which was expected.

This also works:

```
$ npx tslint
No files specified. Use --project to lint a project folder.
```

So my question is, what does `node tslint` do and why does it neither to find the script nor actually run the script?

Comment: TSLint is an extensible static analysis tool that checks TypeScript code for readability, maintainability, and functionality errors. you have to run tslint from project directory where you have initialised tslint.json file. for CLI command refer https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/